# Python Selenium attribute value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I need the value for attribute with the name "serial" which I am unable to get with my limited skills in python & selenium. I am looking for the output of "0000013". and please guide me how to capture the element in a loop as well. many thanks.

What I have tried:

```
for data in soup.find_all(class_='CoreData'):
    h = data.find('h2')
    k = h.find('serial')
    print(k)
```

It returns value of "None" instead of the value of "Serial"

```
<h2>                        <!--For Verified item-->
                                        <a class="clickable" style="cursor:pointer;" onmousedown="open_item_detail('0000013', '0', false)" id="View item Detail" serial="0000013">
                                            Sample Item
                                        </a>
                                    <!--For unverified item-->
                                </h2>
```

Comment: I don't see a class `CoreData`. Please update more of the HTML and the full code you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of `serial`, try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h2>
 <!--For Verified item-->
 <a class="clickable" id="View item Detail" onmousedown="open_item_detail('0000013', '0', false)" serial="0000013" style="cursor:pointer;">
  Sample Item
 </a>
 <!--For unverified item-->
</h2>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for data in soup.find_all("a", class_="clickable"):
    print(data["serial"])
```

Output:

```
0000013
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the attribute `serial` i.e. **0000013** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 a.clickable[onmousedown^='open_item_detail']"))).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2//a[@class='clickable' and starts-with(@onmousedown, 'open_item_detail')]"))).get_attribute("serial"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```